# How do I pass data between threads?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I want to move data from one thread to another but my code only works for the first value I pass instead of saving the first 5 values into the list and printing them out afterwards
here's my code:

```
 private readonly ConcurrentQueue<int> _queue = new ConcurrentQueue<int>();
    private readonly AutoResetEvent _signal = new AutoResetEvent(false);

    public void Thread1()
    {
        List<int> values = new List<int>();
        int lastInput;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        while (values.Count < 5)
        {
            _signal.WaitOne();
            _queue.TryDequeue(out lastInput);

            values.Add(lastInput);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < values.Count; i++)
        {
            sb.Append(String.Format("{0}\n", values[i]));
        }
        MessageBox.Show(sb.ToString());
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Thread th1 = new Thread(Thread1);
        th1.Start();

        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        {
            _queue.Enqueue(i);
            _signal.Set();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you see the "important" notes in the remarks section [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.eventwaithandle.set(v=vs.110).aspx) ? I suspect that most of your `Set()` calls are doing nothing

Comment: It looks like you are trying to build your own implmentation of [BlockingCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312(v=vs.110).aspx), just use the one built in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see what you are trying to do, and @MarcGravell's comment is correct, and also what @mariosangiorgio is saying is true. What you can do as a work-around is use a `Monitor Wait/Pulse` mechanism instead. Try the following:

```
    private readonly Queue<int> _queue = new Queue<int>();
    private readonly object _locker = new object();

    public void Thread1()
    {
        List<int> values = new List<int>();
        int lastInput;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        while (values.Count < 5)
        {
            lock (this._locker)
            {
                // wait until there is something in the queue
                if (this._queue.Count == 0)
                {
                    Monitor.Wait(this._locker);
                }

                // get the item from the queue
                _queue.Dequeue(out lastInput);

                // add the item to the list
                values.Add(lastInput);
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < values.Count; i++)
        {
            sb.Append(String.Format("{0}\n", values[i]));
        }
        MessageBox.Show(sb.ToString());
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Thread th1 = new Thread(Thread1);
        th1.Start();

        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        {
            lock (this._locker)
            {
                // put something in the queue
                _queue.Enqueue(i);

                // notify that there is something in the queue
                Monitor.Pulse(this._locker);
            }
        }
    }
```

So, essentially what you will be doing is calling a loop that is going to try and consume a total of 5 items. If the consumer thread sees that there are no items in the queue to consume, it will wait until the producer puts some items in the queue. Once the producer puts the items in the queue, it will tell the waiting consumer thread that it is ready to go! The consumer thread will then un-block and consume whatever item may be in the queue.

Now additionally, if you consider @mariosangiorgio comment, you are actually using a concurrent collection. So he is right, there is not actually a need to block. So if you want to do your own blocking/unblocking experiment, you could go with my implementation and just use a regular `Queue` (non-concurrent). Or, like @mariosangiorgio said just remove the `AutoResetEvent` and let the `ConcurrentQueue` do its thing.

Although, keep in mind that if you don't block, you will continuously loop and run the CPU until something actually get's `Dequeue`'d.

Answer (score 1):

I thought I'd offer a different solution to the problem. You certainly could use `AutoResetEvent` and `ConcurrentQueue`, but it makes the code hard to understand, get right and reason about.

You should generally try to use a library with a simpler abstraction. I like Microsoft's Reactive Framework (NuGet "Rx-Main", "Rx-WinForms", or "Rx-WPF").

Rx lets you create a LINQ-like pipeline of operations that are performed asynchronously where you can specify the schedulers (threading) you'd like to use.

This is the equivalent to your code:

```
IDisposable subscription =
    Observable
        .Range(0, 5, Scheduler.Default)
        .ToArray()
        .Select(xs => String.Join(Environment.NewLine, xs))
        .ObserveOn(this)
        .Subscribe(x => MessageBox.Show(x));
```

The use of `Scheduler.Default` pushes the computation to a new thread for a windows app. So the string generation occurs away from the UI thread. The `.ObserveOn(this)` pushes the computation back to the UI (as `this` refers to the current form - you could use any UI element instead of `this`).

`subscription` is an `IDisposable` so you can call `subscription.Dispose()` at any time to cut the computation short if it is long running and you want it to stop.

The Rx library is very powerful and it offers you a lot of operators to perform some very complex computations in a relatively simple form.

Comment: Also a big fan of Rx! I think you helped me out with one of my questions once about Rx.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in you `_signal.Set();` and `_signal.WaitOne();`.

That is going to work the way you want only if you have an interleaving where `WaitOne` is always called before a `Set`. I suspect that in your case you have the following event interleaving:

```
_signal.WaitOne(); // This waits for the first set
_signal.Set(); // This notifies the first `WaitOne`
_signal.Set(); // This doesn't notify anything
_signal.Set(); // This doesn't notify anything
_signal.Set(); // This doesn't notify anything
_signal.Set(); // This doesn't notify anything
_signal.WaitOne(); // Nothing is going to set this
```

Since you're using a `ConcurrentQueue` you don't need to use an `AutoResetEvent`. Just remove it and everything should work.

Comment: If they just remove the `AutoResetEvent` won't they be looping and just eating CPU until something gets queue'd?

Comment: When I first learned about multi-threading I had a guy yell at me for doing that, and said I didn't listen to anything he said... I'm not proud of it, but it stuck with me I guess...